# Pro Tools HEAT?

Tags: pro-tools, heat, upgrade

What do you think? How does it sound? Is this just another carrot for me to buy PT8?

- Ryan

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea how good HEAT sounds but, I am frankly a bit saddened by this and the direction that AVID is taking with Digidesign.  My sentiments are shared by many on the DUC.  I would pay twice what they are asking for Pro Tools 8 HD if it was without bugs.  Instead of adding features that many users don't need and introducing new bugs and inconsistencies, they need to do a thorough rewrite of Pro Tools without adding any features.

New features don't interest me if they make the program crash.  It doesn't crash for me in 7.4 so that's where I will stay until the next 'stable' version is released.

I still love Pro Tools, I just wish they had more accountability for stability and made that a priority.

Comment: well said! I concurr

Comment: Amen. I agree.. That is why I haven't upgraded yet, either!

Answer (score 2):

Not much help i can give, but there is this thread on (on? in? at?) [gearslutz](http://www.gearslutz.com/board/so-much-gear-so-little-time/520792-pro-tools-heat.html)
As usual you have to dig trough the BS, hope there's useful information in there

Comment: @Filipe Thanks - that's why I asked it here! No BS!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds HOT!

(Please disregard this answer.)

Comment: Hah! If you can't handle the HEAT, stay out of the studio.